# How does maven checkstyle plugin work for both building and reporting?

Tags: maven, checkstyle

I'm using this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

Somehow it works in the build lifecycle and the site lifecycle. I thought it had to be declared within the build tag and the reporting tag to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: including the above dependency adds the plugin to my classpath, so i'm assuming that when a plugin is on the classpath, it's goals can be used in the lifecycles and the build and reporting tags are only for configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of configuration - http://roman-ivanov.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-to-use-snapshot-checkstyle-version.html

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't answer my question. Somehow I am able to create checkstyle reports through 'mvn site' and also see checkstyle results when running the default/build lifecycle. How is this possible if I am only including the dependency mentioned and not including the build nor plugin tags in my pom?